# IMPORTXML reading decimal separator as thousands separator

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, localization, importxml

When I import this item via `IMPORTXML` and the spreadsheet locale is US (or other country that uses dot as decimal separator) it works fine:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/cias-listadas/empresas-listadas/ResumoEventosCorporativos.aspx?codigoCvm=19348&tab=3.0&idioma=pt-br#fechar-modal", 
 "//*[@id='ctl00_contentPlaceHolderConteudo_grdBonificacao_ctl01_ctl12_lblPercOuFator']")
```

> Result = `0.01`

When I set the locale to Brazil, for example, it understands this dot as a thousand separator and imports the number as `1.000.000.000` (the source 
number is `0.01000000000`).

My problem is that I need to deal with both numbering format.

I have checked this [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/100415/trying-to-use-google-sheets-importhtml-to-import-a-table-it-forces-content-to) already, but the proposed solutions didn't work. Any ideas? So far I had to create a separated spreadsheet to deal with both formats, but it'd be good if IMPORTXML wasn't that clever trying to figure out what's the data format.

Answer (score 2):

Use the xPath `concat` function to append a text character to the imported value to force Google Sheets to threat it as text. I.E. the following formula appends a `_`.

`=IMPORTXML("http://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/cias-listadas/empresas-listadas/ResumoEventosCorporativos.aspx?codigoCvm=19348&tab=3.0&idioma=pt-br#fechar-modal", 
"concat(//*[@id='ctl00_contentPlaceHolderConteudo_grdBonificacao_ctl01_ctl12_lblPercOuFator']/text(),'_')")`

Then the `_` character could be removed by using SUBSTITUTE or other methods. Example:

`=SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML("http://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/cias-listadas/empresas-listadas/ResumoEventosCorporativos.aspx?codigoCvm=19348&tab=3.0&idioma=pt-br#fechar-modal", 
"concat(//*[@id='ctl00_contentPlaceHolderConteudo_grdBonificacao_ctl01_ctl12_lblPercOuFator']/text(),'_')"),"_","")`

Comment: How to use concat when importxml returns an array? I put concat in my xpath query but only the first row of the imported data shows up.

Answer (score 1):

- **you can either correct it with** **`*1E-11`**:

  ```
  =IMPORTXML("http://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/cias-listadas/empresas-listadas/ResumoEventosCorporativos.aspx?codigoCvm=19348&tab=3.0&idioma=pt-br#fechar-modal"; 
  "//*[@id='ctl00_contentPlaceHolderConteudo_grdBonificacao_ctl01_ctl12_lblPercOuFator']")
  *1E-11
  ```

[image]

---

- **or by using US sheet where you import it and then use** **`IMPORTRANGE`** **to import it in your Brasil sheet:**

  ```
  =IMPORTRANGE("1LBTbmztidw3517QHVqI-g3KAkiPp7qoCtOHhEtoc4iQ"; "Sheet1!A1")
  ```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm already using IMPORTRANGE already, as a workaround. The `*1E-11` won't work as sometimes I get an integer.

Comment: you could wrap it in IF function to differentiate between states with and without `*1E-11`

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue using IMPORTXML and I just changed to IMPORTHTML to resolve it.

Comment: Welcome. It's good to know that IMPORTHTML work for you but it will not work in all cases. Have you tried to use it for the case shared by the OP?